# How do I switch between multiple channels on the YouTube app for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, youtube

I have two YT channels under the same g-mail ID and I can't for some reason choose between which channel I want to see open on the app. Everytime I sign in, I'm automatically directed to the channel which is not the default channel and I never use.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the 'Account' screen there should be a little arrow next to your name, if you click on that you should be able to switch channels. As for making it default you may just want to sign out of both accounts and then sign back into them in order of priority. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I just found out how to fix this on a Apple TV 5th Gen:

1. Go to "Add an account" on your TV
2. On the next screen you'll have by default the option to "Sign up using your YouTube mobile app" . Instead of doing that, select "Try Another Way."
3. That will generate a code, that you should enter here:  youtube.com/activate (make sure you're logged into the gmail address that contains the multiple accounts).
4. On your browser you'll have the option to select which one of the 2 accounts you want to add to your tv (the mobile app defaults to the first account).
5. Voilà. You should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is a little confused when signing in on another device.
When you head to the activate page, if you click on the account that's probably not the one you want on the Apple TV, if you click it, your other usernames will appear.

Thanks again for the help.